# symfony 4 ChoiceType selected value to be send to another form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am starting with symfony and I am just trying to use ChoiceType to define a multiple select in my page but not sure about how can I retrieve the selected items, I need their IDs because later I will do one select on database with them.

That's my code:

Controller nº1:

```
$areas = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Area::class)->findAll();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('name', TextType::class)
->add('areas',  ChoiceType::class,
    array('label' => $translator->trans("areas_label") . ':',
        'choices' => $areas,
        'choice_label' => 'getAreaName',
        'multiple'=>true)
)
->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();

return $this->redirectToRoute('results',
    array('name' => $data['name'], 
          'selected_areas'=> ??? ));   <--- any idea?
}
```

Controller nº2: I'm able to get in 'results' these values using request->get

```
/**
* @Route("/results", name="results")  
*/
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $selected_areas = ????
```

Thanks for any help on this,

Comment: Piece of advice: Separate your Form classes from Controllers. 
Create your Form class in Form directory, extend FormType, override resolveOptions method, implement buildForm method just like you did above, and you can access it like $form->buildForm('class', 'initialData', 'options') - with this approach you have more control over your form classes and your code is much cleaner. Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
 $name = $form->get('name')->getData();
 $areas = $form->get('areas')->getData();


return $this->redirectToRoute('results',
    array('name' => $name, 'areas' => $areas             
          ));
}
```

Then, in twig template you can access them by:

```
{{ name }}
{{ areas }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use EntityType for that, you can check it here https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html .
Then the next code will return you selected entities.

```
$areas = $form->get('areas')->getData();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed my code to use EntityType instead of ​ChoiceType​ but then I don't know how to retrieve the selected values, I am using:
$selected_areas= $form->get("areas")->getData();
but it seems that it doesn't know which entity is being used, instead of that it returns an arrayCollection where I can't use getters from my entity.

Comment: It should return you arrayCollection, and each element of that array is your Area entity. You can not use methods from Area class on arrayCollection, you can use foreach loop for that:
`foreach($areas as $area){
  $area->yourMethodName();
}
`